# Older Android API doesn't appear in SDK Manager

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I recently attempted to install API 13, which is required by a popular android library project I recently downloaded.  To my dismay, when I ran SDK Manager I did not see API 13 or several others.  I did some googling and found some posts about a problem running SDK Manager while eclipse is running, so I shut down eclipse and ran SDK Manager on its own, only to achieve the same results - API 13 and several other older APIs do not appear.  I've also checked and unchecked Updates,Installed,and Obsolete check boxes, as well as the 'force https sources to use http' box in the options without any luck.

I currently have API 2.3, 4.0.x, and a few other already installed.  I used to see these older APIs in the past.  Have they been removed from the download site?  Or is it possible to install these APIs manually, i.e. download them and copy them to the androidsdk folder?

Comment: I see api 13 with updates/new and installed checked (with obsolete unchecked)

Comment: Try cleaning your cache (Tools > Options, then click the "Clear Cache" button in the dialog). Then, do Packages > Reload to pull down a fresh roster of available SDKs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your SDK. If that doesn't work, then check to make sure that your AVD is pointed at your current SDK files.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. OP didn't ask anything about AVD (Android Virtual Device)

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant that SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the Obsolete option has a tick by it at the bottom of the Android SDK Manager.
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was "deprecation" if you open you sdk manager and you click in `Packages/Show Obsoletes Packages` and that's it, the api level 14 (in my case) will appear.